# Stuck on POST screen while booting (power on/ restart)

Tags: boot, 16.04, thinkpad, bios

Everything was working fine till yesterday, now it is stuck on the POST screen while I am powering on or, restart.

It is working only if I press `ESC` or `Enter` button, which takes me to diagnostics screen and the rest of the startup works as expected.
I am not getting any error or, any beep sound.

Model: Lenovo Thinkpad L460

OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Single boot only)

Thanks[image]

Edit: Any multiple keypresses starting it normally.
`Enter` key taking me to bios options, `f12` to the boot selection menu.

Comment: Is there any error message? Can you add a picture of the entire screen while the POST appears.

Comment: No error message, I have added the post screen.

Comment: Great, does any of the Function keys respond (Try hitting them continuously right after you press the power key when you turn it on), focus mainly on F2, F9 and F10.

Comment: It's bit wired but any key (including function keys) press seems starting it normally. F12 taking me to boot selection screen which is normal. Enter giving me bios options.

Comment: I think this is the regular behavior when boot device couldn't be found.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I will keep observing the behavior + do a system test as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved once I executed `sudo apt autoremove`

[image]

It reconfigured my GRUB, which I suspect was causing the issue.

> Generating grub configuration file ...
>
> Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.